# How to get the test result attachments from azure devops (api)

Tags: azure, api, azure-devops

I can get and upload attachments to the test result (green on screen)
But how can I get result attachments that uploaded manually by Web runner (red on screen)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaXay.png)

Use this API doc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

The point is I see the attachment id by mouse hover, so the ID aasighned to the attachments, but can not get it via API.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SysBR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I opened the F12 mode to capture the request calls in the current page, and I searched my attachment name in the network traces and found the rest api to list my target attachment.

[image]

And the api below looks similar to that in the doc you shared about [Attachments - Get Test Sub Result Attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/get-test-sub-result-attachments?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), and with this api, you could get the attachment ID.

```
get https://vstmr.dev.azure.com/<org>/<proj>/_apis/tcm/runs/8/results/100000?detailsToInclude=5&api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

So I modify the [Attachments - Get Test Sub Result Attachment Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/get-test-sub-result-attachment-zip?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), adding the query filter of `detailsToInclude=5` like below.

```
https://vstmr.dev.azure.com/<org>/<proj>/_apis/tcm/runs/<runID>/results/<resultID>/attachments/<attachmentID>?detailsToInclude=5&api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

And I download the attachment correctly.

Comment: Thank for reply. I got your solution. But I use the Azure DevOps Python API provided by microsoft opencode
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api

so, I can not modify the URI, only restricted with lib clients.

I need some how to get the testSubResultId to use this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/get-test-sub-result-attachments?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: I find the solution!
This block called as Iterations. So I need get iteration for this test result, iteration has id's for attachments.
@Ceeno Qi-MSFT, thank you to give me the vector for investigation!

Answer (score 0):

Azure has Test Point instance

> A test point is a unique combination of test case, test suite, configuration, and tester

[Test Point - Get Points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test-point/get-points?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)

From the Test Point I got "lastTestRunId" and the relevant Test Result: [Results - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) .
Test Result has the attachments by his own, but also manual testing test result iterations there, that in turn has attachments as well.
So, to get attachment id I should got the Iteration first:
[Iterations - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/iterations/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)
-> "attachments": []